# get html DIV content from asp.net c# codebehind event

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, html

I want to get HTML DIV content via asp.net C# code behind event.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Report.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.Report.Report" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title> 
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#_Hidden_CrystalReportContent').hide();
        $('#_Hidden_CrystalReportContent').html("<b>I want to get Current value. 1<sup>st</sup></b>");

    });        
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="_Hidden_CrystalReportContent">I want to get Current value.</div>    
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

My code behind file as below.

```
public partial class Report : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string s = Request["_Hidden_CrystalReportContent"].ToString();
}
}
```

But I still cannot get div content value.
Please let me get your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Make the div runat="server" to access on server.

*Html*

```
<div id="_Hidden_CrystalReportContent" runat="server">
```

*Code behind*

```
string htmlOfDiv = _Hidden_CrystalReportContent.innerHTML;
```

*Javascript*

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#<% _Hidden_CrystalReportContent.ClientID %>').hide();
    $('#<%= _Hidden_CrystalReportContent.ClientID %>').html("<b>I want to get Current value. 1<sup>st</sup></b>");

});
```

Making a div server accessible by puttin runat="server" attribute cause the changed client id if CLientIDMode is not static. You will need to use ClientID attribute to get client id of div in javascript.

**Edit:** based on comments. You are trying to get the updated html, if so you then you wont get it as on post back only html form elements are posted. Put the changes in some hidden field and assess it on server.

*In html*

```
<input type="hidden"  id="hdnDivContents" runat="server">
```

*In javascript*

```
$('#<% hdnDivContents.ClientID %>').val("<b>I want to get Current value. 1<sup>st</sup></b>");
```

*In code behind*

```
 _Hidden_CrystalReportContent.innerHTML = hdnDivContents.Value;
```

Comment: I did it as you suggested, But It return me only "I want to get Current value." . I want to get most update value from Jquery function  "<b>I want to get Current value. 1<sup>st</sup></b>". But I cannot get  updated data. Please suggest me again

Comment: You are calling on document.ready currently. You need to put it in some function and call it when required.

Comment: I created `Button1 OnClientClick` and put my function to that client event. But nothing change.

Comment: You are trying to get the updated html? if you then you wont get it as on post back only html form elements are posted. Put the changes in some hidden field and assess it on server.

Comment: The reason why I don't try to use hidden field is I cannot know how much amount of HTML string need to dynamically append to Div content.